# UIAlertControllerで押されたボタンをTrue/Falseで取得したい

Tags: swift

UIAlertControllerを使用して「OK」と「キャンセル」のボタンを持ったActionSheetを表示し、
「OK」の場合trueを、「キャンセル」の場合falseを返す関数を実装したいと考えています。

以下のように実装してみたのですが、ユーザーの選択を待たずに関数が終了してしまいます。
ユーザーの選択を戻り値と取得するにはどのようにするのが良いでしょうか？
アホな質問で申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
/// 確認メッセージ表示
class func confirm(vc: UIViewController, strMsg: String, strTitle: String = "") -> Bool {
    var ret: Bool = true
    let dialog = UIAlertController(title: strTitle, message: strMsg, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    let act1 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action in
        ret = true
    }
    let act2 = UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル", style: .Cancel) { action in
        ret = false
    }
    dialog.addAction(act1)
    dialog.addAction(act2)

    vc.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return ret
}
```

Comment: 全然アホな質問ではなく、イベントドリブンや非同期処理の考え方に慣れない人がはまりがちな落とし穴の一つでしょう。「戻り値として取得する」のにこだわっていると最適な解決策が見えてこなくなります。「その値を使って何をしたいのか」を教えていただけませんか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
今のところ考えている1つの用途は、レコード削除処理前の確認です。
trueであれば削除処理を実行し、キャンセルであれば何もしないという流れです。
他にも何かしらの確認が必要な処理の前にこの関数をCallすることを想定しています。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメントしていただいたような使い方であれば、true/falseを受け取るようなクロージャーを渡せるようにしてしまうのが簡単だと思います。

```
extension UIViewController {
    /// 確認メッセージ表示
    func confirm(strMsg: String, strTitle: String = "", handler: Bool->Void) {
        let dialog = UIAlertController(title: strTitle, message: strMsg, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let act1 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action in
            handler(true)
        }
        let act2 = UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル", style: .Cancel) { action in
            handler(false)
        }
        dialog.addAction(act1)
        dialog.addAction(act2)

        self.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

ついでですが、特定クラスのクラスメソッドとせずに、UIViewControllerのextensionとして定義すると、どのUIViewControllerからも使えて便利ですよ。

使うときはこんなイメージになります。

```
@IBAction func deleteRecord(_: AnyObject) {
    //何らかの前処理
    //...
    confirm("レコードを削除して良いですか", handler: {confirmed in
        if confirmed {
            //削除処理を実行
            //...
        } else {
            //キャンセルであれば何もしない
        }
    })
    //これ以降はメソッドの中に処理を書いてはいけない
}
```

Comment: 想定する動きを実装することができました。ありがとうございます！
クロージャーというものをよく理解できていないので勉強しないと！です。またextensionで定義するという方法についても教えて頂きありがとうございます。まだまだ問題が山積みなのですが、このextensionで問題が1つ解決しそうです。<(_ _)>

Comment: お役に立てたのであれば何よりです。Swiftではクロージャーの使い勝手が良くなって、使われどころも多いので、少しずつ学習を深められると良いと思います。蛇足ですが、将来は世界進出を目指すという可能性が少しでもあるのであれば、ユーザの目に触れる文字は、たとえ"OK"のような短いものでも`NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "")`のように書く癖をつけておくと、将来のアプリの国際化が少し楽になりますよ。

Comment: 多言語化の件、仰る通りかと思います。
地道に勉強して知識を増やしていければと思います。アドバイスに感謝です。